# to csv seems to destroy some decimal values

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Calculator on the left shows the correct number.
In the source frame and when printing the frame instantly before the to_csv, everything is fine.
Anyone got an idea what could happen? I googled into oblivion but can't seem to solve it.

Comment: This is a floating point issue.

Comment: Float [round-off error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error), to add to @user1558604's comment above.

Answer (score 3):

It's not destroying any values.  The number `3521.12` cannot be represented exactly in binary.  It's an infinitely repeating decimal.  Your calculator, your frame view, and your frame print are all rounding that value to make it easier for you to read, as it should.  The csv is storing the exact decimal value.  When you read it back in, it will once again display correctly.  That's just the way floating point works.

Comment: thank you, this thing was driving me crazy. Is there anything I can do to prevent this? In case I want to use the generated file in excel for example, it's really annoying that a wrong value is given - EDIT: I just checked it, not even py shows the value exactly after reading it back in. The same wrong value as in the csv.

Comment: Excel will display it correctly if you format the column to 2 decimals.